# Rust: PartialEq trait in generics

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to write some basic generic:

```
pub struct MyGeneric<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>
}

impl<T> MyGeneric<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, item: T) {
        if !self.vec.contains(&item) {
            self.vec.push(item);
        }
    }
}
```

but getting an error:

```
priority_set.rs:23:10: 23:35 error: the trait `core::cmp::PartialEq` is not implemented for the type `T`
priority_set.rs:23      if !self.vec.contains(&item) {
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I have tried to implement PartialEq in several ways looking into API docs, but failed to find a solution by myself. I'm not very familiar with traits conception, so I need a help with it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to limit all possible values for `T` to ones that implement `PartialEq`, because the definition of `Vec::contains()` requires it:

```
pub struct MyGeneric<T> {
    vec: Vec<T>
}

// All you need is to add `: PartialEq` to this impl
// to enable using `contains()`
impl<T: PartialEq> MyGeneric<T> {
    fn add(&mut self, item: T) {
        if !self.vec.contains(&item) {
            self.vec.push(item);
        }
    }
}

fn main()
{
    let mut mg: MyGeneric<int> = MyGeneric { vec: Vec::new() };
    mg.add(1);
}
```

Generic types require specifying some bounds on their parameters most of the time, otherwise it would not be possible to verify that the generic code is correct. Here, for example, `contains()` is using operator `==` on items, but not every type may have that operator defined. The standard trait `PartialEq` defines operator `==` so everything that implements that trait is guaranteed to have that operator.

Comment: Could you please extend your example code? I think I'm starting to understand, but not quite sure.

Comment: @bender.rodriges I have included minimal example that compiles in Rust 0.11.

Comment: Now I get it! I did thought that <T: SomeTrait> notation meant derivation. All this time I've tried to implement it like fmt::Show trait. Thank you!